# Bootstrap/HTML: Links not working on iPad

Tags: html, ios, twitter-bootstrap, ios-simulator

I took a web site and wrapped it up to run as a mobile app for iOS and Android. Everything is working fine on the different platforms except for 1 page on iPad. There are links at the top of the page that jump to locations further down the page. On iPad regardless of what link you click on, it jumps to the same location.

I've double check to make sure my hrefs and ids are correct and as I said they all work on other devices just not the iPad and only on this particular page.

I can replicate the issue using the iOS simulator for iPad. At this point I'm not entirely sure what code would even be relevant to show here.

If anyone has any ideas as to what might cause this issue or how to fix it I'd appreciate it.

Edit:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container searchArea">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexa">A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Quotas and Maximum Flight Distances</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexb">B&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Information on Sensors</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexbappendix1">App 1&nbsp; Annotation of Data Collected During an Observation Flight</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexc">C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Information on Observation Aircraft</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexd">D&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Certification of Observation Aircraft and Sensors</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexdappendix1">App 1&nbsp; Methodologies for the Verification of the Performance of Sensors Installed on an Observation Aircraft</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexe">E&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Procedures for Arrivals and Departures</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexeappendix1">App 1&nbsp; Designation of Sites</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexf">F&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Pre-flight Inspection and Demonstration Flights</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexg">G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Flight Monitors, Flight Representatives and Representatives</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexh">H&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Coordination of Planned Observation Flights</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexi">I&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Information on Airspace and Flights in Hazardous Airspace</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexj">J&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Montreux Convention</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexk">K&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Information on Film Processors, Duplicators and Photographic Films and Procedures for Monitoring the Processing of Photographic Film</a></p>
                <p class="annexes_info_text"><a href="#annexl">L&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Open Skies Consultative Commission</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid" id="annexa">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <p><strong>ANNEX A <br/>QUOTAS AND MAXIMUM FLIGHT DISTANCES</strong></p>
                </div>
                ****Content****
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <br/>
        <div class="row-fluid" id="annexb">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <p><strong>ANNEX B <br/>INFORMATION ON SENSORS</strong></p>
                </div>
                ****Content****
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <br/>
        <div class="row-fluid" id="annexbappendix1">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <p><strong>APPENDIX 1 TO ANNEX B <br/>ANNOTATION OF DATA COLLECTED DURING AN OBSERVATION FLIGHT</strong></p>
                </div>
                ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexc">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX C <br/>INFORMATION ON OBSERVATION AIRCRAFT</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexd">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX D <br/>CERTIFICATION OF OBSERVATION AIRCRAFT AND SENSORS</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <p><strong>SECTION I. GENERAL PROVISIONS</strong></p>
                        ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexdappendix1">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>APPENDIX 1 TO ANNEX D <br/>METHODOLOGIES FOR THE VERIFICATION OF THE PERFORMANCE OF SENSORS INSTALLED ON AN OBSERVATION AIRCRAFT</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexe">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX E <br/>PROCEDURES FOR ARRIVALS AND DEPARTURES</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexeappendix1">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>APPENDIX 1 to ANNEX E <br/>SECTION I. DESIGNATION OF SITES</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexf">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX F <br/>PRE-FLIGHT INSPECTIONS AND DEMONSTRATION FLIGHTS</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <p><strong>SECTION I. PRE-FLIGHT INSPECTION OF OBSERVATION AIRCRAFT AND SENSORS OF THE OBSERVING PARTY</strong></p>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexg">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX G <br/>FLIGHT MONITORS, FLIGHT REPRESENTATIVES, AND REPRESENTATIVES</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <p><strong>SECTION I. FLIGHT MONITORS AND FLIGHT REPRESENTATIVES</strong></p>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexh">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX H</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <p><strong>CO-ORDINATION OF PLANNED OBSERVATION FLIGHTS</strong></p>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexi">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX I <br/>INFORMATION ON AIRSPACE <br/>AND FLIGHTS IN HAZARDOUS AIRSPACE</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexj">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX J <br/>MONTREUX CONVENTION</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexk">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX K <br/>INFORMATION ON FILM PROCESSORS, DUPLICATORS AND PHOTOGRAPHIC FILMS, AND PROCEDURES FOR MONITORING THE PROCESSING OF PHOTOGRAPHIC FILM</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <div class="row-fluid" id="annexl">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p><a href="#top">Back to Annexes Table of Contents</a></p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p><strong>ANNEX L <br/>OPEN SKIES CONSULTATIVE COMMISSION</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    ****Content****
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try replacing the webview with https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/Ti.WKWebView

Comment: does the link work if you just open it in Safari?

Comment: It does not. I hadn't thought to try that yet. I'm still confused as to why though.

Comment: then it would be useful to see the HTML pages since its not a Appcelerator problem

Comment: Here is a stripped down version of the HTML. I did some testing after you mentioned this and it looks like whatever is causing the issue is in the bootstrap.mini.css somewhere.

Comment: edited the question and removed the Appcelerator parts since it's a bootstrap problem. Solution below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rows are not taking up the correct space. It is not working in Firefox (Linux), too.

Remove the `row-fluid` and change them to `row`. There is no `row-fluid` in the latest bootstrap. Then the row will have the proper height and the jumps will lead to their goal.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick! I don't know that I would have thought to look at the rows. Though I'm not sure why it doesn't seem to effect any of the other pages that have it.  Thanks again miga.